# Ugly Django error: column hello_match.URL does not exist

Tags: python, django

As I play with Django more and more I kinda used to matching `query does not exist` or `relation “users_user” does not exist` errors. But this one is new to me:

```
column hello_match.URL does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "hello_match" WHERE "hello_match"."URL"...
```

syncdb is not working here and I don't have any clue what went wrong.

Comment: Please provide more code details, from where you got this error and what you tried ?

Comment: The problem is I don't know where the problem is. On my DigitalOcean server I changed app's models.py and this happened. I have one clue though. Is there a chance that this happens because one or more packages are installed wrong?

Comment: Give code of changed `model.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you changed the model but did not upgdated the database. Once aging you have to sync db with model.

```
python manage.py makemigration <your app>
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Tried it. I sync or migrate it succesfully, but it's not helping at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Hardcore method**: remove your migration-files from the *hello_match* app and repeat `syncdb`